# Explicit form of this Hermitian operator

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

I would like to solve the following integral equation for a Hermitian matrix:

$$\hat{G}_j = \int_0^1d\alpha \exp[-i\alpha\hat{H}] \partial_j \hat{H} \exp[i\alpha\hat{H}],$$

One possibility is to use the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. So using

$$\exp[A]B\exp[-A] = B + [A, B] + \frac{1}{2!}[A, [A, B]] + \ldots,$$

then by re-writing the integrand of $\hat{G}_j$ and integrating w.r.t. $\alpha$ we obtain

$$\hat{G}_j = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-i)^n}{(n+1)!}C^n_{\hat{H}}(\hat{H}_j),$$

where $C^n_{\hat{H}}(\hat{H}_j)$ is the nth-order nested commutator: $C^0_{\hat{H}}(\hat{H}_j) = \hat{H}_j$, $C^1_{\hat{H}}(\hat{H}_j) = [\hat{H}, \hat{H}_j]$, $C^2_{\hat{H}}(\hat{H}_j) = [\hat{H}, [\hat{H}, \hat{H}_j]]$ and so on. From this infinite series, how can I proceed to find an explicit form of the matrix $G$?

Comment: You are reproducing the adjoint action series of the [Duhamel formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Comments_on_the_general_case). To proceed, you'll have to know a few details of the Lie algebra of $[H,H_j]$, and its commutators with *H*. For instance, if this commutator is proportional to *H*, then nice closed expressions result. Write down what you know about the algebra.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, this prompt was sufficient to give me ideas on the approach. It does indeed yield the same result as using Duhamel's formula. Aside: really enjoyed your book on Quantum mechanics in Phase space!

Comment: Thanks. The book grew as a hobby, at first. A compact application of what i am hinting at above is the [braiding formula here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#Selected_tractable_cases).